# How to forbid executable to read/modify any files except the given directories?

Tags: c, bash, strace, chroot

I guess, I am in a quite common situation. I am a novice teacher and I have to teach my students to the basics of C programming language. Checking their homework takes a lot of time and I am wondering how I can automatize this process. I have decided to use my email address for this purpose. Basically, I would like to write a script (and put it in cron) that checks out my email address for new messages from students, downloads attachments (each student has its own directory, where the source code is stored), compiles them, runs some tests and then sends results back to students. The problem there is that somebody can send to me program that contains commands like **system("rm -rf ../..");**. I would like to prevent from running these commands. But students should be allowed to modify files in their own directories and read files with test data from different directory. Is there a simple and secure way to achieve this? Can you provide some examples, if it is possible?

I know that I am not the first one who asks this question here, but all of answers that I was able to find were unclear to me and were posted years ago. People usually recommend to use **chroot jail** but this approach requires root privileges and, as far as I understand, is not safe, since it is simple to break out of the jail. Also I have read about **strace**, but it prints all system calls into stdin. Is it possible to disallow some system calls or stop the program with strace?

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I don't know what you are teaching, but I hope it's not devops/ sysadmin. Anyway, you could run the programs as a restricted user?

Comment: If you are only teaching basic programming, there are two issues that makes this a bad idea. First, the assignments should not be so large as to make looking at them too time consuming. Second, as the students are beginning programmers, you *should* be looking at their code, not just confirming that the code passes a test suite.

Comment: @chepner, assignments are not so large, but I have a lot of students and I should formally if their algorithms are right and pass through the tests. I am still going to look through their programs, but I hope that test system would help me to do it less carefully and focus only important parts and errors. And I also want to find out how to solve my original problem and able to teach  not only basic programming.

Comment: @andlrc, I am not sure, if I understood what do you mean. Should I create a new user that is allowed to modify only one dir or not? If yes, should I have a different user for every student and how do I change users within script? Do I need root for this?

Comment: Very interesting question. In my school we have a program that do exactly what you need. Maybe you want to check 'Moulinette'@ ecole 42. Anyway I would recommend the approach @alk suggested as it is a really secure way.

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](http://cseducators.stackexchange.com) (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter [through here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators).) We have a few questions about workflow and submitting coding assignments there, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a test VM and mirror it before  running the students' code inside the VM.

Use the mirror to recover from any disaster.

Also you can script the VM to be reinitialised (from the mirror) automagically every night, week, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which flavor of Linux you are using, but have you tried taking a look at [fakechroot](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fakechroot)? It works by creating a shim library which intercepts certain system calls and allows chroots to be used by non-root users. Seems like it might be a good fit for you. If that's not suitable for some reason, you could consider using a container system like [LXC](https://linuxcontainers.org/), or [docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can watch for exported symbols using

```
nm
```

It will show you every functions exported with the prorgram and then if system is exported or any other unauthorized functions you'll see it without executing the program.

Comment: Looks quite good and simple for now, but do not know what call except system I should look for. I should to think about it.  If there will be no other way to catch sytem calls, I will use your approach. Thank you.